# Tool to create a gamepad button mapping diagram?

Tags: diagram, gaming

Do you know of any tool to generate an image that explains the button of a game ? I'm organizing an event where beginners will play various games, and I'd like to make a cheat sheet of the buttons of each game. Do you know of any tool where I can type in labels for each button of a x360 gamepad, and that will generate a nice button configuration image like we can see in a game manual ?

Comment: draw.io has some good shape drawing etc. if you want web based

Answer (score 0):

You might have to just do it manually via Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop. Or pay someone on fiverr.com to do it for you.

You can make layouts for game manuals in Adobe Indesign

Answer (score 0):

Came across this, but yes there is called Joystick Diagrams.

https://www.joystick-diagrams.com/

It will automatically look at certain games, and output their mappings onto a diagram directly from the game configuration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).